# DOMException: Failed to set remote answer sdp: Called in wrong state: stable

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, socket.io, webrtc

When a 3rd user enters the video conference, I get the following error:

> "**DOMException: Failed to set remote answer sdp: Called in wrong state: stable**"

I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77932342/domexception-failed-to-set-remote-answer-sdp-called-in-wrong-state-stable) that it might be because since two peers are meant to be connected with each other, since there is a third peer coming in the video conference it kind of messes everything up. Therefor, I need to create a new connection for each new peer, which I did here:

```
 clients.forEach((socketListId) => {


        connections[socketListId] = this.createPeerConnection(socketListId); // NEW peer connection for each new user !

        // je collecte mes iceCandidates
        connections[socketListId].onicecandidate = function (event) {
          if (event.candidate != null) {
            socket.emit(
              "signal", // je spread mes icecandidate via "signal"
              socketListId,
              JSON.stringify({ ice: event.candidate })
            )
          }
        }
```

I'm quite clueless at the moment because I tried adding a new RTC connection to my 'connections' array for each new user, but I still get the same error whenever a 3rd peer connects to the room, the first and second peer are loosing connection with each other while the 3rd peer can still hear and see all peers.

I'm thinking maybe an issue with the order of the offer creation?

here's a bigger part of the code:

```
let connections = {}
let socket = null
let socketId = null
let videoElements = 0

const peerConnectionConfig = {
  iceServers: [
    // Serveurs STUN(co avec la plus part des NAT)
    { urls: "stun:stun.services.mozilla.com" },
    { urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302" },

    // Serveur TURN (si un user est derrière un nat restrictif ou un pare feu chiant, un serveur TURN prendra le relais)
    {
      urls: "turn:turn.anyfirewall.com:443?transport=tcp",
      credential: "webrtc",
      username: "webrtc",
    },
  ],
}

class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.myVideo = React.createRef()
    this.iceCandidatesQueue = {}
    this.videoAvailable = false
    this.audioAvailable = false

    this.state = {
      video: false,
      audio: false,
      screen: false,
      showModal: false,
      screenAvailable: false,
      socketId: '',
      messages: [],
      message: "",
      newmessages: 0,
      askForUsername: true,
      username: "",
      usernames: {},
      isSidebarOpen: false,
      requestingSpeech: false,
      speechRequestMessage: "",
      password: "",
      authorizedUsers: [],
      connectedEmails: [],
      currentUserEmail: "",
      isAdmin: false,
      loadingCamera: true,      
    }
    
    axios
    .get(`${server_url}/users`, { withCredentials: true } )
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ authorizedUsers: response.data })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(
          "Erreur lors de la récupération des utilisateurs :",
          error
        )
      })

    this.sourcesPermissions()
  }

  sourcesPermissions = async () => {
    try {
      const videoStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video: true,
      })
      const audioStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
      })

      // en faisant "!!navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia" je vérifie si la methode getDisplayMedia est dispo dans le navigateur
      // si c'est le cas ça veut dire que le navigateur supporte le partage d'écran
      // donc ça me retrourne true et donc je met à jour ma state
      // (state qui va déterminer si j'affiche le bouton de partage ou non)
      const screenAvailable = !!navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia
      this.setState({ screenAvailable })

      if (videoStream || audioStream) {
        // si on a l'aautorisation pour l'audio ou la video de l'user
        window.localStream = videoStream || audioStream // je recupere le flux autorisé par l'user dans window.localStream
        this.myVideo.current.srcObject = window.localStream // j'affiche ce flux dans mon element video
        this.setState({ loadingCamera: false })
      }

      this.videoAvailable = !!videoStream // videoAvailable à true si videoStream est true et vis versa
      this.audioAvailable = !!audioStream // meme délire
      this.screenAvailable = screenAvailable
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
      this.setState({ loadingCamera: false })
    }
  }

  getMediasAndInitConnection = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        video: this.videoAvailable, // videoAvailable = acces video autorisé par user donc this.state.video sera true
        audio: this.audioAvailable, // ...
      },
      () => {
        this.getSources()  // llorsque l'utilisateur arrivera dans la room sa camera/son audio sera activée ou désactivée en fonction des permissions 
        this.serverConnection() // ensuite jenclenche la logique de connexion server notamment en recuperant l'username, l'email, signal pour SDP/iceCandidates etc....
      }
    )
  }
  
  getSources = () => {
    if ((this.state.video && this.videoAvailable) || (this.state.audio && this.audioAvailable)) {
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: this.state.video, audio: this.state.audio })
        .then((stream) => {
          // Call getSources_Success directly or perform any other logic with the stream
          this.getSources_Success(stream);
        })
        .catch((e) => console.log(e));
    } else {
      // If neither audio nor video are enabled, stop the current media stream
      try {
        if (this.myVideo.current && this.myVideo.current.srcObject) {
          let tracks = this.myVideo.current.srcObject.getTracks();
          tracks.forEach((track) => track.stop());
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
  };
  

  getSources_Success = (stream) => {
    window.localStream = stream;
    this.myVideo.current.srcObject = stream;
  
    for (let id in connections) {
      if (id === socketId) continue;
  
      connections[id].addStream(window.localStream);
  
      connections[id]
        .createOffer()
        .then((description) => connections[id].setLocalDescription(description))
        .then(() => {
          socket.emit(
            "signal",
            id,
            JSON.stringify({ sdp: connections[id].localDescription })
          );
        })
        .catch((e) => console.log(e));
    }
  }
  
  signalFromServer = (fromId, body) => {
    let signal = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(`Received signal from ${fromId}:`, signal);

    if (fromId !== socketId) {
      if (signal.sdp) {
        connections[fromId]
          .setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(signal.sdp))
          .then(() => {
            console.log(`ICE Connection State for ${fromId}: ${connections[fromId].iceConnectionState}`);
            console.log(`Signaling State for ${fromId}: ${connections[fromId].signalingState}`);
            console.log(`Setting remote description for ${fromId}, type: ${signal.sdp.type}`);
  
            if (signal.sdp.type === "offer") {
              connections[fromId]
                .createAnswer()
                .then((description) => {
                  console.log(`Answer created successfully for ${fromId}`);
                  connections[fromId]
                    .setLocalDescription(description)
                    .then(() => {
                      console.log(`Local description set successfully for ${fromId}`);
                      socket.emit(
                        "signal",
                        fromId,
                        JSON.stringify({
                          sdp: description,
                        })
                      );
                    })
                    .catch((e) => console.error(`Error setting local description for ${fromId}:`, e));
                })
                .catch((e) => console.error(`Error creating answer for ${fromId}:`, e));
            }
  
            if (this.iceCandidatesQueue[fromId]) {
              this.iceCandidatesQueue[fromId].forEach((candidate) => {
                connections[fromId]
                  .addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate))
                  .catch((e) => console.error(`Error adding ice candidate for ${fromId}:`, e));
              });
              delete this.iceCandidatesQueue[fromId];
            }
          })
          .catch((e) => console.error(`Error setting remote description for ${fromId}:`, e));
      }
  
      if (signal.ice) {
        let iceCandidate = new RTCIceCandidate(signal.ice);
        if (connections[fromId].remoteDescription) {
          connections[fromId]
            .addIceCandidate(iceCandidate)
            .catch((e) => console.error(`Error adding ice candidate for ${fromId}:`, e));
        } else {
          if (!this.iceCandidatesQueue[fromId]) {
            this.iceCandidatesQueue[fromId] = [];
          }
          this.iceCandidatesQueue[fromId].push(iceCandidate);
        }
      }
    }
  };
  

  

serverConnection = () => {
  socket = io.connect(server_url, { secure: true })


  socket.on("signal", this.signalFromServer)

  socket.on("connect", () => {

  socket.emit(
    "joinCall",
    window.location.href,
    this.state.username,
    this.state.currentUserEmail
  )
  socketId = socket.id
  this.setState({ socketId });

  socket.on("update-user-list", (users) => {
    if (users) {
      // si j'fais pas ça il va mdire undefined blablabla
      let updatedUsernames = {}
      users.forEach((user) => {    
        updatedUsernames[user.id] = user.username
      })
      this.setState({ usernames: updatedUsernames })
    } else {
      console.log(
        "Pas encore de user ici.."
      )
    }
  })

 
    socket.on("user-joined", (id, clients, username, email) => {
      console.log(`Utilisateur rejoint: ${username}, ID: ${id}`);
  

// seul l'user qui s'est fait kick va listen " user-kicked" car c'est emit depuis server spécifiquement à la personne kicked et le reste jte fais pas un dessin       
      socket.on("user-kicked", () => {
        window.location.href = "/";  
        socket.disconnect();
      });

      if (id !== socketId) {
        this.getSources(); // ce salaud j'ai dû le metre ici aussi car en mode prod il faut le relancer quand un autre peer se connecte
        message.success({
          content: `${username} a rejoint la conférence.`,
          className: "custom-message",
          duration: 3,
        })
        // si l'id qui vient d'arriver ne correspond pas à mon socketId (moi) alors je play le sound de cette maniere,
        //seul les utilisateurs déjà présents dans la room entendront le son si un new user arrive dans la room
      }

      
      this.setState((prevState) => ({
        usernames: {
          ...prevState.usernames,
          [id]: username,
        },
      }))

      this.setState((prevState) => ({
        connectedEmails: [...prevState.connectedEmails, email],
      }))

      clients.forEach((socketListId) => {


        connections[socketListId] = this.createPeerConnection(socketListId); // NEW peer connection for each new user !

        // je collecte mes iceCandidates
        connections[socketListId].onicecandidate = function (event) {
          if (event.candidate != null) {
            socket.emit(
              "signal", // je spread mes icecandidate via "signal"
              socketListId,
              JSON.stringify({ ice: event.candidate })
            )
          }
        }
 
        // je check si un nouveau user (nouveau videoElement du coup) arrive dans la room
        connections[socketListId].onaddstream = (event) => {
          // c un event de webRTC go voir : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/addstream_event

          let searchVideo = document.querySelector(
            `[data-socket="${socketListId}"]`
          )


          if (!searchVideo) {              
            console.log(`Creating new video element for socketListId: ${socketListId}`);

            videoElements = clients.length // videoElements = nbr de client connectés à la  room..
            console.log("videoElements: ", videoElements) // test adaptCSS
            let main = document.getElementById("main")
            let cssMesure = this.adaptCSS(main)


            let video = document.createElement("video")

            let css = {
              minWidth: cssMesure.minWidth,
              minHeight: cssMesure.minHeight,
              maxHeight: "100%",
              margin: "10px",
              borderStyle: "solid",
              borderColor: "#bdbdbd",
              objectFit: "fill",
              backgroundImage: `url(${backgroundBlck})`,
              backgroundSize: 'cover', 
              backgroundPosition: 'center', 
              backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat' 
            };
          
            for (let i in css) video.style[i] = css[i]
          
            video.style.setProperty("width", cssMesure.width)
            video.style.setProperty("height", cssMesure.height)
            video.setAttribute("data-socket", socketListId)
            video.style.borderRadius = "25px"
            video.srcObject = event.stream
            video.autoplay = true
            video.playsinline = true
            video.onclick = this.handleVideoClick
            const videoId = "video_" + socketListId;
            video.setAttribute("id", videoId);
            // video.classList.add("video-with-username");
            // video.setAttribute("data-username", username);
            video.srcObject = event.stream;
            main.appendChild(video)
      
            this.adaptCSS(main);

          }else{
            console.log(`Updating existing video element for socketListId: ${socketListId}`);

            searchVideo.srcObject = event.stream;

          }

        }
          
        if (window.localStream instanceof MediaStream) {
          // Ajout du stream à RTCPeerConnection..
          console.log(`Adding stream to connection for user ${socketListId}`);

          connections[socketListId].addStream(window.localStream);
        } else {
          message.error('Votre caméra n\'est pas disponible !!');
        }        
      })

      if (id === socketId) {
        console.log("Local user has joined. Initiating offer creation logic.");
    }
     // Ici, je vais gérer le scénario au cas où un user se co à une salle avec des utilisateurs déjà présents.
     //Cet utilisateur va envoyer son offre à tous les utilisateurs déjà présents dans la salle.        

     if (id === socketId) {
      for (let otherUserId in connections) {
        if (otherUserId === socketId) continue;
      
        let connection = connections[otherUserId];
      
        // Assurez-vous que la connexion a correctement ajouté le flux local
        if (window.localStream instanceof MediaStream) {
          connection.addStream(window.localStream);
        } else {
          console.error('Erreur : la caméra n\'est pas disponible.');
          continue;
        }
    
        console.log('Stream bien ajouté. Creation de l offre pour user : ' + otherUserId);
    
        connection.createOffer()
        .then((description) => {
          console.log(`Offer created successfully for ${otherUserId}. Setting local description.`);
          connection.setLocalDescription(description);
        })
        .then(() => {
          console.log(`Local description set successfully for ${otherUserId}. Sending signal.`);
          socket.emit(
            "signal",
            otherUserId,
            JSON.stringify({ sdp: connections[id].localDescription })
          );
          console.log(`Signal emitted successfully to ${otherUserId}`);
        })
        .catch((e) => console.error(`Error during offer creation or setting local description for ${otherUserId}:`, e));
      }
    }
    
      
    })
  })
}

  
createPeerConnection = () =>   {
  let peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(peerConnectionConfig);

  return peerConnection;
}
```